# Quartz: Veto job if job already scheduled or running

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

It appears the behavior of `@DisallowConcurrentExecution` on a job is to queue it when it's redundantly scheduled (for **now** meaning there's currently a job trying to be fired right now or already executing).  I want to instead skip execution, even when the new trigger doesn't use a schedule and is simply using `.startNow()` . Basically, I'm trying to avoid queueing up the same job from multiple triggers to be run back to back.

I looked into implementing a `TriggerListener` like the following and removing `@DisallowConcurrentExecution` but it doesn't seem reliable as I'm still getting a race condition when scheduling the same job repeatedly all at once and they're all past their chance to veto (already decided not to) before execution even starts.

```
import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext;
import org.quartz.SchedulerException;
import org.quartz.Trigger;
import org.quartz.listeners.TriggerListenerSupport;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class VetoAlreadyRunningTriggerListener extends TriggerListenerSupport {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(VetoAlreadyRunningTriggerListener.class);

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return VetoAlreadyRunningTriggerListener.class.getSimpleName();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean vetoJobExecution(Trigger trigger, JobExecutionContext context) {
        try {
            boolean veto = context.getScheduler().getCurrentlyExecutingJobs().stream()
                    .anyMatch(otherContext -> otherContext.getJobDetail().getKey()
                            .equals(context.getJobDetail().getKey()));

            if (veto) {
                LOGGER.info("Vetoing as another job with the same key is already running.");
            }

            return veto;
        } catch (SchedulerException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Scheduler exception while deciding whether to veto job.  Defaulting to VETO!");
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a good solution to this problem?  It seems like it should be a common use case and Quartz it supposedly pretty mature and feature rich but I can't seem to find a reasonable answer anywhere.

Comment: Maybe synchronize your method vetoJobExecution.

Comment: @Mr_Thorynque Not that kind of race condition unfortunately.  Current running jobs is always empty at the point of reaching the trigger listener.